# WPF: Custom routed event with extra information

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I have a normal WPF window, let's call it `TopLevel` which has a bunch of controls in it, among other things a simple `ListView` which should log certain events in different elements in the application.

So suppose I have a `Grid` in `TopLevel` which contains a bunch of user controls called `Task`. Each `Task` has an object associated with them as a public property, let's call it `Order`, as well as a standard checkbox.

Now I want `TopLevel` to receive an event whenever the user checks a checkbox in a `Task`, but the event should contain the `Order` object as well, so I can work with it from `TopLevel` to put it into the event log.

How do I do that? I'm guessing I want to use routed events for it, but I can't figure out how to get the checkbox click to "find" `Order` to send it upwards to `TopLevel`.

Comment: @TabbyCool: I decided to look for other options before deciding whether to use your method or not. I'll give you the "correct answer" anyways.

Comment: Thanks, haha!  Did you find anything promising?  I'd be interested in seeing how you implement this if you do decide on an alternative solution  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
        Task task = FindParentTask(checkBox);
        Order order = task.Order;
    }
```

Since you need to traverse up the visual tree to get to Task, you could try a bit of recursion...

```
public FrameworkElement FindParentTask(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        if (element.Parent.GetType() == typeof(Task))
            return element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        else
            return FindParentTask(element.Parent as FrameworkElement);
    }
```

I've just tested this method to retrieve the parent Expander for a CheckBox on one of my UserControls, it's several levels up the visual tree, nested in a heap of StackPanels, Grids and DockPanels, worked a treat.

Comment: So I can just convert a `DependencyObject` into whatever type I want like that?

Comment: Are you referring to checkBox.Parent?  If the underlying object is already of type Task, then yes, I think so.  Do you have a sample of your code? Can't hurt to try it though, it's only a few lines  
:-)

Comment: Also, the checkbox is not the immediate child of the `Task` so I would need to traverse upwards in some manner to get to the `Task`.

Comment: It should still be achievable as you can access the Parent, then access the Parent of the Parent etc.

Comment: That's where I get stuck at the moment, because how do I access the parent of a dependency object?

Comment: Cast it to a FrameworkElement (or the actual type, if you know what the object is).  Or see my edited answer, I need to check that this actually works though.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I've tried this and it works perfectly.  I used it to traverse up the tree from my CheckBox to get to the parent Expander, had to go through several levels of StackPanels, DockPanels and Grids to get there.